# how do I check if the stars have been clicked? (Jquery Star rating plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, rating-system

I'm using this plugin http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing.
I was attempting to make a client-side validation system which figures out whether 
stars have been clicked. 
I was wondering how you can do it.

In my javascript file, I have

```
    $('#star1').click(function (){
        document.getElementById('star1').checked=true;
        return false;
    });
```

I'm using radio button typed stars and have html code like this,

```
    <input id="star1" name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="1"/>
    <input id="star1" name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="2"/>
    <input id="star1" name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="3"/>
    <input id="star1" name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="4"/>
    <input id="star1" name="star1" type="radio" class="star" value="5"/>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think it should be `document.getElementById('star1').checked='true';`

Comment: They all say star1 as the id.  You can't have multiple nodes with the same id

Comment: Start by making your ID's unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/2xTwb/

Hope it fit your cause `:)`

**scripts**

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.rating.js"></script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.rating.css">
```

**code**

```
$(".voting-star[value='3']").attr("checked", true);

$('.voting-star').rating({
    callback: function(value, link) {
        alert(value);
    }
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to check the `checked` property.

```
$('.star').click(function (){
   if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
     //...
   }
   return false;
});
```